# How to retrieve the AuthorizationCode after authorizing Google+ using PhoneGap's InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, inappbrowser

I'm trying to implement an OpenAuth2 authorization with Google on a PhoneGap application. What is happening is that after successfully authorizing the application, I am not being able to retrieve the Authorization Code.

I followed the [tutorial here](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html) to do that, and I really liked the way it is being made. Basically it registers a loadstart event on the InAppBrowser to that when the `http://localhost` starts getting loaded, the loadstart event is triggered, then it retrieves the authorization **code**, do its work and close the window. The problem is that the windows doesn't get closed and just shows an error stating that the localhost url could not be loaded.

I know I don't have a localhost in phonegap, but the point is to intercept the code from the url and close the window before the request is completed.

The code can be found [on this tutorial](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html). They are basically the same.

So my questions here are:
1 - Is there an easier way to retrieve the authorization code? 
2 - If question 1 doesn't have an answer, what am I doing wrong in the current approach?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Ok, I think that what is happening is that InAppBrowser events are not firing...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using window.on( and you use window.addEventListener(